# Is it possible to get table type definitions from INFORMATION_SCHEMA?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I know that user defined types are stored in `information_schema.domains`, but is it possible to get the definitions for types which are of type `table type`?

To be clear I am looking for the actual table type definition:

e.g. I want to get the column definitions for `myTableType`

```
CREATE TYPE myTableType AS TABLE(
     Id INT,
     SomeValue NVARCHAR(20)
);
```

Comment: What version of SQL Server? Is there a reason you can't use the new DMVs?

Comment: You are looking for the equivalent of `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` for user defined table type definition, yes?

Comment: @billinkc That is correct.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

To get the list of columns for a user-defined table type, run this.  You'll need to substitute your table name for `some_table_type`:

```
SELECT *
FROM sys.columns
WHERE object_id IN (
  SELECT type_table_object_id
  FROM sys.table_types
  WHERE name = 'some_table_type'
);
```

Comment: I'm looking for the actual definition for the type. I will edit my post to make this clear.

Comment: @Romoku See my edit.  I think you're looking for that after your clarification.

Answer (score 10):

Get the list of table type,columns and datatype for a user-defined table type.

```
select tt.name AS table_Type, c.name AS table_Type_col_name,st.name AS   
table_Type_col_datatype
from sys.table_types tt
inner join sys.columns c on c.object_id = tt.type_table_object_id
INNER JOIN sys.systypes AS ST  ON ST.xtype = c.system_type_id
```

Answer (score 9):

Get column name, details of its type and nullability:

```
SELECT tt.name     AS Table_Type,
  c.name           AS Column_Name,
  st.name          AS Datatype, 
  CASE WHEN st.name = 'numeric' THEN '(' + Convert(varchar(5), c.precision) + ',' + Convert(varchar(5), c.scale) + ')' 
  WHEN st.name IN ('char', 'nchar', 'varchar', 'nvarchar') THEN '(' + Convert(varchar(5), c.max_length) + ')' 
  ELSE '' END      AS Size,
  CASE WHEN c.is_nullable = 0 THEN 'NOT NULL,'
  ELSE ',' END     AS Nullable
FROM sys.table_types tt
  INNER JOIN sys.columns c ON c.object_id = tt.type_table_object_id
  INNER JOIN sys.systypes st ON (st.xusertype = c.system_type_id AND st.uid = 4)
ORDER BY tt.name, c.column_id
```

Answer (score 4):

Using Management Studio it is also possible to access a visual representation of custom / user-defined table types, just as you can with regular tables.

The difference is that user-defined tables appear under the ***programmability*** node in the object explorer, as shown below, instead of under ***Tables***:

[image: Custom user-defined table type]

Answer (score 0):

With less code, using  [sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-exec-describe-first-result-set-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) you can do something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set  (N'DECLARE @TEST myTableType ; SELECT * FROM @TEST', null, 0) ;
```

Here are some of the columns:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

This query returns the information from standardized `information_schema` views and should work in any database:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM information_schema.user_defined_types t
JOIN information_schema.attributes a ON
  t.user_defined_type_catalog=a.udt_catalog 
  AND t.user_defined_type_schema=udt_schema
  AND t.user_defined_type_name=a.udt_name
```

I didn't test it in SQL Server, but in PostgreSQL, but they should work.

Comment: I wasn't the downvote, but this does not work in SQL Server.